# How to @MockBean when there are 2 of the same type?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, mockito

Going to try to provide simplified example (hopefully I don't mess up somewhere)

Let's say I have 2 @Beans of the same type, but one of them is annotated

```
@Configuration
public class FooProvider {

  @Bean
  public Foo foo1() {...}

  @Bean
  @SpecialFoo
  public Foo foo2() {...}

}

@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SpecialFoo {}
```

In my application, Spring seems to be ok with having one annotated bean and one un-annotated bean. The annotation is a @Qualifier

```
@Configuration
public class BarProvider {

  @Bean
  public Bar bar1(Foo foo1) {...}

  @Bean
  public Bar bar2(@SpecialFoo Foo foo2) {...}
}
```

All of that works. Program loads up and Spring doesn't complain.

But the issue arises when I try to test it.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class MyTest {

  @MockBean
  Foo foo1;

  @MockBean @SpecialFoo
  Foo foo2;

}
```

At this point, I get an error like

> No qualifying bean of type 'Foo' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: foo1, foo2

What am I doing wrong?

Special request: I would prefer not to have to annotate `foo1` also or add a `@Qualifier` just because it's a lot of places I need to change. I'd rather the default bean be the un-annotated one.

Comment: Also, what's the difference between `@MockBean("beanName")` vs `@MockBean @Qualifier("beanName")`? I tried those but didn't seem to work though I could be misusing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I found works

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class MyTest {

  @MockBean(name = "foo1")
  Foo foo1;

  @MockBean @SpecialFoo
  Foo foo2;

}
```

I needed to tell Spring which Foo @Bean I was replacing with this mock by giving it the name of the bean it's replacing. If the MockBean has a `@Qualifier` or `@SpecialFoo` Qualifier annotation, then it doesn't need this naming. So only un-annotated bean requires this.

To answer my question in the comment, it seems these 2 are equivalent:

```
@MockBean(name = "foo1")
```

and

```
@MockBean @Qualifier("foo1")
```

Hope this helps others

Comment: Well, this didn't work for me until I removed `@SpringBootTest` and used only `SpringExtension.class`.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
@Configuration
public class FooProvider {

  @Bean("foo1")
  public Foo foo1() {...}

  @Bean("foo2")
  public Foo foo2() {...}

}

...

@Autowire
@Qualifier("foo1")
Foo foo1;

@Autowire
@Qualifier("foo2")
Foo foo2;
```

Comment: This will work, but as I mentioned in post, I'd rather not add an annotation or @Qualifier to `foo1` because it appears in a lot of places. You get an upvote though for a working solution. Though it should be mentioned that @Qualifier needs to be added to the @MockBean, which was the original question

Answer (score 0):

Try adding like:

```
@Primary
public Foo foo1() {
    ...
}
```